# Continuous independent variable divided into two levels without discretion

Tags: regression, continuous-data, categorical-encoding

As far as I know, for differentiating between different levels of an independent continuous variable in regression model, you can convert it into a dummy variable with a reference level and other levels taking values one or zero. However, in [Parkin and Rotherham (2010)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0967070X10000399) they estimate a linear regression model that evaluates speed against gradient, and they split their gradient variable into negative and positive levels, without turning it into a binary dummy variable.  Their model is:

$$\text{Speed} = \text{constant} + a \times \text{Uphill Gradient} + b \times \text{Downhill Gradient}.$$

For instance, if an observation has $\text{Gradient} = 0.15$, they input this as
$\text{Uphill Gradient} = 0$ and $\text{Downhill Gradient} = 0.15$.  What I do not understand is how they use gradient as two variables (uphill and downhill gradients) but they do not use dummy variables, and instead substitute the real value of gradient.

**My question:** Can we divide continuous variable into levels like this without making them a dummy variable?

Comment: Could you provide a bit more context as the link appears to be an abstract and paywall? You'll need to explain more precisely what they are doing.

Comment: Perhaps searching for broken stick regression or segmented linear regression will help you to clarify things.

Comment: This formulation can be seen as an *interaction* between a dummy for up/down hill (coded as $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$) and the gradient.  It can also be seen as a regression against two nonlinear transformations of the gradient $X$: namely, its positive part $\max(X,0)$ and its negative part $\max(-X,0).$  It's readily related to yet another regression with independent variables $X$ and $|X|.$ Evidently, then, one *can* "divide a continuous variable into levels like this."  If you seek some deeper meaning or underlying theory, it's probably not there--but is this the sort of analysis you're after?